# iOS SDK - Salesforce

Tags: ios, sdk, salesforce

How to fix it?

```
2020-10-08 14:46:56.406001-0700 iOS13NativeSwiftTemplate[12199:771469] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=3 "Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing" UserInfo={RBSAssertionAttribute=<RBSDomainAttribute| domain:"com.apple.webkit" name:"Background" sourceEnvironment:"(null)">, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing}>
```

2020-10-08 14:46:56.453117-0700 iOS13NativeSwiftTemplate[12199:771469] [ProcessSuspension] 0x10e9fe440 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS Background assertion 'WebProcess Background Assertion' for process with PID 12225, error: Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=3 "Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing" UserInfo={RBSAssertionAttribute=<RBSDomainAttribute| domain:"com.apple.webkit" name:"Background" sourceEnvironment:"(null)">, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing}
2020-10-08 14:46:56.460457-0700 iOS13NativeSwiftTemplate[12199:771469] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}>
2020-10-08 14:46:56.460597-0700 iOS13NativeSwiftTemplate[12199:771469] [ProcessSuspension] 0x10e9fe4c0 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS Background assertion 'WebProcess Background Assertion' for process with PID 12225, error: Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}

Operations with Storage and Sync work. but even 13NativeTamplate app is not working

```
    let request = RestClient.shared.request(forQuery: "SELECT id, firstName, lastName, phone, email, mailingStreet, mailingCity, mailingState, mailingPostalCode FROM Contact WHERE AccountID = '\(acct.id)'", apiVersion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error message while converting from old UIWebKit to WkWebKit.  With old UIWebKit, I would instantiate a UIWebView in IB and link to its code instantiation with:

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

With WkWebKit, you can’t do this.  Instead, I started with:

fileprivate var webView: WKWebView!

and instantiating it in the following function to replace the view with the webView:

```
override func loadView() {
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    view = webView
}
```

I discovered that when I was dismissing the view controller with webView, that I was getting the message.  It finally dawned on me that I probably needed to get rid of the webView before dismissing the view controller.  I made the following adjustments:

```
class myVC: UIViewController {

    fileprivate var webView: WKWebView?

    deinit{
        // print("myVC: deinit\n")    // Debug
        // Remove links to webView
        view = UIView()
        webView = nil
    }
}

extension myVC {
    
    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView?.uiDelegate = self
        webView?.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}
```

So, made webView an optional and clear links to it when the controller is deinit’d.